# How much catnip does a kitten require?

Tags: kittens-game

When I have to many kittens I get out of catnip and my kittens die. So I was curious how much catnip a kitten requires?

Comment: How much catnip would a cat nip if a cat would nip catnip?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each kitten's base cost is 0.85 catnip per tick. Note that this cost can be reduced by [Pastures](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings#Pasture), which reduce this number by 0.5% each and [Unicorn Pastures](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings#Unicorn_Pasture) which reduce this number by 0.15%. (Also, the Pasture reduction is subject to a diminishing returns effect when you push it past 75% reduction, so kittens' cost will never quite hit 0)

The relevant bit of the code, for those who are interested, is right near the top of village.js

```
catnipPerKitten: -0.85, /* amount of catnip per tick that kitten consumes */
```

Comment: it's 0,5% not 5% see [here](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings#Pasture)

Comment: @Serverfrog correct. It is indeed 0.5%, otherwise pastures should cost a lot more or they would be overpowered

Comment: @Serverfrog Whoops! Was a typo, I was in a hurry to get this written up before heading out this morning. Thanks. (I had left out unicorn pastures to avoid minorly spoiling them, since Unicorns are meant to be a bit of a surprising find)

Comment: is it additive or multiplicative? If I got enough pastures, would my catnipPerKitten drop to 0? Or would it get 5% smaller every time, approaching by never reaching 0?

Comment: @corsiKa It adds together, so twenty pastures is -10%. Can't reach -100%, though, which I mentioned in the answer already.

Comment: What is the diminishing return formula after 75%?

Comment: Am on my phone, so can't read the code for the exact details. Some info is at http://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/2flfdp/some_new_player_qs_well_2/ckaz4d9